# SIGILL in GetMethodID while "Evaluate Expression" is OK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I want to call back Java code from native code.
The Java code:

```
public final class Underlying {
    public static native int setOnEventListener(OnEventListener listener);
    public interface OnEventListener {
        int EVENT_TEST = 1;
        int onEvent(int code, String msg);
    }
}
```

The C++ code (I omit some checks to make it clear):

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
Java_packageName_Underlying_setOnEventListener(JNIEnv* env, jclass type, jobject listener) {
    jclass clz = env->GetObjectClass(listener);
    // assign to static jobject
    eventListener = env->NewGlobalRef(listener);
    // assign to static jmethodID
    onEventMethodID = env->GetMethodID(clz, "onEvent", "(ILjava/lang/String;)I");
}
```

**SIGILL** (signal SIGILL: illegal instruction operand) occurs in `GetMethodID`. But I evaluate the same sentence by **Evaluate Expression** in Android Studio and everything is OK.

There must be some differences between reality and Evaluate Expression. One difference I could think of is that the calling thread may be different. `setOnEventListener` was originally called in UI thread, so I created a new thread to do this, but nothing changed.

Comment: It would be much clearer if you attach related crashlog from logcat.

Answer (score 0):

I found two things lead to this error.

1. The return type is `jint`, then a `jint` must be returned.
2. In Android Studio, **Make Project** sometimes doesn't rebuild the C++ code to APK, **Rebuild Project** is needed in this situation.